# ReferenceError: show_agent_stats not defined

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to show a MySQL table query in a script that gets shown on a button click. When the button is clicked it calls a function that outputs to a DIV tag. The function is in another script page called functions.php and is included at the top of the current page vicidial.php. When the button is clicked i get the above error message, im sure its something simple but om not seeing it, here is the calling button and the DIV tag i want the results to print to;

```
     (vividial.php)
    <button onclick="show_agent_stats();">Hey there</button>
    <div id="agent_stats"></div>

     (functions.php)
      function show_agent_stats(){

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var oldHTML = document.getElementById("agent_stats").innerHTML;
    var newHTML = "<?php include("dbtable.php");?>";
        return document.getElementById("agent_stats").innerHTML= newHTML;


            <?php
            }
```

any help finding the source of this error is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`<button onclick="show_agent_stats();">Hey there</button>`

The above is trying to access a javascript function called `show_agent_stats()`. You have created this function in `PHP`.

I highly recommend doing some research as to the difference between server side code and run time code.